# Microsoft Chart Control: Prevent Series from appearing in Legend

Tags: mschart

In the MS Chart control (which they bought from Dundas), I have three series that need to be plotted.

Two of the series should have an entry in the Legend, but the third should not.

I've tried these lines of code, but none work:

```
Chart c = new Chart();
ChartArea ca = c.ChartAreas.Add("main");
Legend lg = c.Legends.Add("mainLegend");
Series s1 = c.Series.Add("s1");
Series s2 = c.Series.Add("s2");
Series s3 = c.Series.Add("s3");

// ... populate the 3 series with data...

s1.Legend = "mainLegend";
s2.Legend = "mainLegend";

// I've tried these:
s3.Legend = ""; // gives an error about a nonexistent legend named ''
s3.LegendText = ""; // just shows "s3" in the legend
```

How do I prevent the series from appearing in the legend?

Comment: Not familiar with the particular control in question, but would it be possible to add a second legend, add the third series to it, and then hide that legend?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use:

```
s3.IsVisibleInLegend = false;
```

Disclaimer: Only tested in (ASP).Net 4, VS 2010. Your mileage may vary...